# company-mode with python inserts weird characters

Tags: python, company-mode

Company mode suggests the right completions, but when I press `RET` I get weird characters, probably denoting the position, I was expecting to be able to cycle between each of these spots with tab or at last

For example, I get this

```python
    auth_endpoint(${1:read_msg}, ${2:sio}, ${3:sec_websocket_key})$0
```

Comment: [company-mode  troubleshooting](http://company-mode.github.io/manual/Troubleshooting.html).

Comment: It sounds like you don't have `yasnippet` installed. And apparently somewhere there is a missing warning about not being able to function without it.

Comment: I don't have yasnippet installed indeed. I didn't realized that one were dependence of another, thank you!